# Can the FORCESEEK query hint be used on tables being queried against on a linked server? (I.e. as part of a distributed query)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, linked-server, hints, distributed-queries

I have a query that uses the FORCESEEK hint and runs fine on the server where the database I'm querying lives. If I try to run the same exact query remotely from a different server (targeting the original server), I get the following error:

> Msg 7436, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   The query processor could not produce a query plan because FORCESEEK or FORCESCAN hints on table or view 'TableBeingQueried' cannot be used with remote data sources. Remove the hints and resubmit the query.

Example T-SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table3.Field5
FROM Server1.Database1.Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Server1.Database1.Table2 AS T2 WITH (FORCESEEK) -- Index exists for T2.Field2
    ON T1.Field1 = T2.Field2
INNER JOIN Server1.Database1.Table3 AS T3 WITH (FORCESEEK) -- Index exists for T3.Field3
    ON T2.Field4 = T3.Field3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `OPENQUERY()` to be able to query the linked server and apply `FORCESEEK` / `FORCESCAN` hints.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM
OPENQUERY(
[Server1],
'SELECT DISTINCT Table3.Field5
FROM Server1.Database1.Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Server1.Database1.Table2 AS T2 WITH (FORCESEEK) -- Index exists for T2.Field2
    ON T1.Field1 = T2.Field2
INNER JOIN Server1.Database1.Table3 AS T3 WITH (FORCESEEK) -- Index exists for T3.Field3
    ON T2.Field4 = T3.Field3;');
```

Answer (score 3):

You CANNOT use FROCESCAN or FORCESEEK on remote data sources.

Reference: [Hints (Transact-SQL) - Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

**The FORCESCAN hint has the following restrictions:**

> The hint cannot be specified for a remote data source.

**When using the FORCESEEK hint (with or without index parameters), consider the following guidelines:**

> The hint cannot be specified for a remote data source. Error 7377 is
>   returned when FORCESEEK is specified with an index hint and error 8180
>   is returned when FORCESEEK is used without an index hint.